# How to change the date format to accept date with or without / in Orbeon Forms

Tags: date, format, orbeon

I want that Orbeon validate these two formats when I insert in date input field  date like this "12/11/2016" or "12 11 2016".

I try to insert two properties in `properties-local.xml`. Orbeon accepts two formats but not totally when I insert 12 11 2016, it accepted but when I type "12l 11 2016" an error shows. The problem that when I correct the error Orbeon still doesn't accept this date "12 11 2016" and when I type "12/11/2016" the date is accepted and the error is removed.

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date"
    value="[D][M][Y]"/>
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date"
    value="[D]/[M]/[Y]"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a few formats are supported as per the [documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/xforms.html#for-xfinput):

- `[M]/[D]/[Y]` e.g. 11/5/2008 (also called "North America format")
- `[D]/[M]/[Y]` e.g. 5/ 11/2008 (also called "European format")
- As a variation, you can use another separator such as a dot (e.g. `[D].[M].[Y]`) or dash (`[D]-[M]-[Y]`)
- As a variation, you can write `[M01]` and `[D01]` if you want day and months on one digit to be prefixed with a `0`, e.g. 11/05/2008

So your format, `[D][M][Y]`, won't work. It is not possible right now to support this format without making changes to the Orbeon Forms implementation.